# Blogging and uploading videos from a remote computer (and teaching it to someone else with no experience at all)

Tags: web-development, web-services, ftp, podcast

I'm looking for a program that I will host on my server, so that my customer can upload media files and text to it. The program should then present that media in a website.

Context: I'm working on a website for someone who will be taking a trip to Europe and wants to be able to post videos and blogs. The site is hosted through Dreamhost, and I can probably teach him how to upload a video via FTP. The problem is getting the website to link up with his videos and actually display them in an organized way. I'm using iWeb to build the website (I know, don't cringe, I'm not a professional), and it has a page option that allows the user to upload a podcast and a page for a blog, which would be great if I knew how to utilize RSS feeds and podcast software that would allow him to upload these posts remotely from (probably) a (non-Mac w/o iWeb) PC.

Does anyone have any suggestions for software that organizes podcasts and blog information like this, and possibly allows them to be organized for an iWeb site format? Again, I'm relatively inexperienced in this kind of technology, I generally stick to raw Java and C-type programming, and I'm still learning HTML, which is why iWeb seemed like a good option to get aesthetics right.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Do I get it right: You are looking for a program that you host on your server that your customer will be uploading media files and texts to. You then want that program to change your website to contain that information. If I got it wrong please do [edit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/18770/edit) your question to clearly state what the program you are looking for should do.

Comment: @Angelo Fuchs No, I think that's right.

Comment: Did you consider a CMS?

Comment: What are the "media files" you want to use ? Pictures (jpeg ? Metadata ?) and movies only ? If you are "new" to HTML/CSS/PHP/JavaScript, I think a CMS (like WordPress) is the way to go. Easy to use, nice interface to post pictures and videos, lots of free themes/plugins and highly "tuneable" with relatively basic CSS knowledge.

Comment: I think you guys are right, I'm going to try the CMS path! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use the WordPress Content Management System (CMS) because it is free and open-source, which will fit in well with the format I'm using to create the website.

As it stands, I am integrating it alongside my preexisting website, and I'm adding a tab at the top of the website that will link to the WordPress site and database. I may change this form of integration later, but it seems to be working for now.